# Finding transfer function and tuning cutoff frequency of High-Pass FIlter

Tags: transfer-function, high-pass-filter, cutoff-frequency

I have a schematic for a High-Pass filter that has a cut-off of around 7Hz. I obtained the designed online and want to tune it to have a cutoff of 5Hz instead.

I assumed I would proceed in the following way:
1. Find the transfer function H(s)
2. Equate 20log|H(s)| to -3dB

Would this be the correct approach ?

In any case, I am having trouble deriving the transfer equation and would appreciate some help to solve this.

Thank you[image]

Comment: It's an MFB filter - you should be able to google it.

Comment: If you found it online, why can't you modify it online? [This](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuHikeisan.htm) should help.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a first attempt to determine the transfer function of this filter using KCL and KVL. While the approach is perfectly valid, there was a mistake in one of the founding equation and the valorous contributor had to start all over from scratch. I am going to apply the fast analytical techniques or FACTs as described in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) I wrote.

The principle is to chop this complicated 3rd-order circuit - actually a second-order considering the degenerate case - into a succession of smaller sketches you can solve almost by inspection, without writing a single line of algebra. You first determine the time constants involving each capacitors by "looking" into the connecting terminals as the component is temporarily removed from the circuit. When you do this exercise, the remaining capacitors are left in their dc state which is an open circuit. Then, you alternatively short one capacitor while you "look" through the connecting terminals of the other ones. This is what I have done below where a dc operating point from SPICE confirms the analysis. In these simple cases, no need to write a line of algebra, just inspect the circuit and confirm the response with SPICE by reading the bias points:

[image]

Once we have all the time constants we need, we can determine the zeroes using the generalized expression involving high-frequency gains H. These gains are determined when capacitors are set in their high-frequency states (short circuit). Use SPICE and bias the input with a 1-V source and check what the output is. This is the gain you want. Again, inspection is easy here as most of these gains are 0 except one which is the op-amp open-loop gain:

[image]

Once you have these elements, assemble them following the below Mathcad sheet and compare the results with those given by this [site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuHikeisan.htm).

[image]

Results are similar but the expression does not fit the *low-entropy* form which lets you determine the cutoff frequency and the quality factor. A bit of factorization is necessary as indicated below:

[image]

And finally, the simulated transfer function comparing all curves is given below:

[image]

The cool thing with the FACTs is really the divide-and-conquer strategy which lets you individually solve simple circuits and then assemble them all at the end. If you make a mistake - and it was the case solving this exercise - you identify the guilty sketch and correct it while the rest remains intact. A real gain of time!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyE5V0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5=0\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}=0\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_2=0\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}=0\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_3\$:

$$\text{V}_3=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{R}_5\text{V}_\text{x}}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag5$$

So, the transfer function is:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{x}}=-\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag6$$

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}\tag9$$

So, the transfer function will be:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{v}_3\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{p}\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{\text{R}_2\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}\text{R}_5}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}+\text{R}_2\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\text{R}_2\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag{10}$$

So, we must use the transformation \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$).

---

Now, we can find the cut-off frequency using the following equation:

$$\left|\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\left|\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega_0=\dots\tag{11}$$

And using your values, we get:

$$\omega_0=\frac{1250}{121}\sqrt{\frac{2}{47}\cdot\left(\sqrt{193889}-17\right)}\approx43.8459\space\text{rad/sec}\tag{12}$$

Which is the same as:

$$\text{f}_0=\frac{625}{121\pi}\sqrt{\frac{2}{47}\cdot\left(\sqrt{193889}-17\right)}\approx6.9783\space\text{Hz}\tag{13}$$

I found that using the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=C1 = 220*10^(-9);
C2 = 220*10^(-9);
C3 = 220*10^(-9);
R2 = 47000;
R5 = 220000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{(C1 C2 R2 R5 \[Omega]^2 )/(\[Sqrt](1 + 
         R2 ((C1 + C2 + C3)^2 R2 - 2 C2 C3 R5) \[Omega]^2 + 
         C2^2 C3^2 R2^2 R5^2 \[Omega]^4)) == 
    1/Sqrt[2]*C1/C3, \[Omega] >= 0}, \[Omega]]]

Out[1]={{\[Omega] -> 1250/121 Sqrt[2/47 (-17 + Sqrt[193889])]}}
```

Comment: Hi Jan. I follow you up to and including (11). I can see that at the cut-off frequency the response is 0.707 times the magnitude at very high frequency (infinite frequency). But I don't understand how you get from (11) to (12). How do you get wo from the transfer function? Thanks if you can help.

Comment: @James The cut-off frequency is defined by the frequency where it is 3dB lower than the maximum point, and that maximum is point is here at \$\omega\to\infty\$. I used mathematica to find it, that is software.

Answer (score 0):

Both filters have a Q of just about 0.707, a Butterworth response, and a gain of -1.
Mine has a cutt-off freq of 5Hz.

[image: MFB Filter]

The input signal is the red trace (3.5V rms) and the blue trace is the output which is down 3dB at 5Hz.